# Calculate call cost from rate table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cdr

I am trying to compare call rates between two telephone providers. I have two tables, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE 18185_rates (
  calldate DATE,
  calltime TIME,
  calledno VARCHAR(20),
  duration INTEGER(8),
  callcost FLOAT(5 , 3 )
);

CREATE TABLE int_rates (
  dialcode VARCHAR(20),
  description VARCHAR(20),
  callcost FLOAT(5 , 3 )
);
```

The 18185_rates contains call data records from a phone system, some example values as follows:

```
calldate,calltime,calledno,duration,callcost
2013-07-30,11:21:38,35342245738,10,0.050
2013-07-30,16:19:25,353872565822,37,0.130
2013-08-02,08:31:12,65975636187,1344,0.270
2013-08-05,11:03:53,919311195965,2356,1.640
```

The table int_rates contains tariff data for calls from another provider in the following format:

```
dialcode,description,callcost
1,USA,0.012
1204,Canada,0.008
1204131,Canada,0.018
1226,Canada,0.008
1226131,Canada,0.018
1242,Bahamas,0.137
1242357,Bahamas Mobile,0.251
1242359,Bahamas Mobile,0.251
```

I am trying to run a comparison, so that I can see how much the calls in 18185_rates would have cost with the other provider. I can't work out how to join the two tables based on the variable length dialling code in int_rates.

After some help from @Gordon Linoff below, I've come up with the following code:

```
SELECT 
    r.*,
    (SELECT permin
     FROM int_rates ir1
     WHERE r.calledno LIKE CONCAT(ir1.dialcode, '%')
     ORDER BY dialcode DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS newcostpermin
FROM
  18185_rates r;
```

Comment: @FilipeSilva sorry I only put a subset of the data as examples, there should be a price for every call from 18185_rates in the int_rate table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to match each phone number to the cost that has the longest prefix.  Here is an approach:

```
select ir.*,
       (select callcost
        from int_rates ir
        where r.calledno like concat(ir.dialcode, '%')
        order by length(ir.dialcode) desc
        limit 1
       ) as TheirCost
from 18185_rates r;
```

This is using a correlated subquery to find the longest dialcode that matches the beginning of the call.  This will be `NULL` if nothing matches.  Also, this will not be efficient and cannot use indexes.

EDIT:

There are different ways to approach this.  The simplest is just to duplicate the subquery:

```
select ir.*,
       (select callcost
        from int_rates ir
        where r.calledno like concat(ir.dialcode, '%')
        order by length(ir.dialcode) desc
        limit 1
       ) as TheirCost,
       (select description
        from int_rates ir
        where r.calledno like concat(ir.dialcode, '%')
        order by length(ir.dialcode) desc
        limit 1
       ) as TheirDescription
from 18185_rates r;
```

In practice, I would pull a primary key out in the first subquery and then join back to the table, to get whatever fields I want from the that table.  However, you don't specify the table layout and if the first query has reasonable performance, then doing it twice should be ok too.

Comment: Thanks, your assumption is correct about the prefix matching. Think you have a typo on the first line, should it be "select r.*"?

Comment: Have added some updates to the question above based on your help - would be interested to hear your thoughts on the last bit of the puzzle! Thx

Comment: thanks, that last bit worked fine, bit slower but perfect for my purposes.